# Keyboard doesn't work on selecting boot disk macOS

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp

I'm using macOS 10.12.1 on mac mini 2012 with Plume 84 keyboard attached to back of it. When I try to boot into bootcamp disk(by holding option key while booting procedure), it doesn’t work.

- keyboard is plugged into the back of the computer directly. It's connected on rightmost port.
- Win 10 is installed on bootcamp section
- I tried rEFInd, selecting disk screen appeared but keyboard didn't allow me to select disk. I pressed the arrow key but focus didn't move.
- BOOTCAMP disk isn't appeared on 'boot disk' section in Preferences app.
- Other keyboard(Tesoro M7) does work which uses PS2 cable with usb converter. It even worked when plugged into USB Hub.

Since the other keyboard worked, I think it would be the matter of Plume 84 keyboard itself. But I doubt if that's something possible happen, and would appreciate if anyone can give me explanation how this happened. Also, if there's some way I can use this keyboard to be recognized while booting procedure, I would be grateful if you enlighten me. Any suggestion are appreciated as well.

Apology if this post is duplicate one. Every solution I googled didn't work.

Comment: Are you saying the Keyboard isn't recognised at all (not even holding down Option)? Or are you saying that it's working, but once you're in the startup manager it no longer works?

Comment: the keyboard isn't recognized at all and would boot into macOS disk. Once it boots and only then keyboard is recognized. As of rEFInd, it showed me the list of disks available by default but keyboard didn't work which led me unable to select bootcamp disk and would boot into macOS as well. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a common issue experienced by almost everybody that uses bootcamp on a Mac. There are a few ways that you can try to fix/do.

**Method 1**

Have you checked the installed drivers on the bootcamp side. Launch the bootcamp application on the Mac and deselect disinstall windows 10 or lower versions. Then select the "Get latest drivers from Apple" and insert a USB driver inside the computer.

[image: Bootcamp]

Make sure that the USB is working well and formatted on FAT32. 
If you're experiencing issues try to format using SDFormatter that is free. Press the continue button and let it download the latest drivers.

[image: SD Formatter Screenshot (Windows Only)]

Keep the USB inserted and boot on Windows10. In normal conditions, Windows should recognize the driver data and launch it automatically but if it doesn't recognize, just launch it like another program on your computer via the USB drive.

After doing this process reboot your computer and the latest Mac drivers including the CD reader, keyboard, SD reader and many more hardware will work.

**Method 2**

Make sure that your keyboard is recognized by Windows10. Check your hardwares inserted/paired with the computer you're using through the control panel. If the keyboard is not seen here contact Apple Support.

**Note:** First Method should work and in normal conditions drivers are not working on almost every user out there.

*Take care and let me know if you need more help.*

**Arda**

Comment: Hi, Arda. Thank you so much for bothering to answer my question including all those screenshots and notations. However, my question was about while booting procedure—before that white apple logo appear—, and yes, I tried to install all the required drivers(downloaded via Bootcamp Assistant) but somehow, it didn't finish even after I waited whole night, in spite of that keyboard is recognized when login screen appears. Maybe I should consider reinstalling Bootcamp but I doubt if it would solve my problem. Again, thank you so much for reply, really appreaciated it :)